# Is として in this sentence adverbial?

Tags: usage, grammar

I was trying to get a full understanding of this sentence's structure:

> 政府が学校の建設を計画しているが、遅々**として**進まないので、現地にあるNGO組織が学校づくりを支援している

I know `として` as "As; In", like in `教師として`, "as a teacher", but in this sentence I don't think it has that meaning;  I found other meaning (apart from; even; from a viewpoint), none of which seems to apply here.

I'm guessing the `と` part is meant to be adverbial, i.e. `遅々 (slow) > 遅々と (slowly)`, but if that's the case I'm not sure about the `して` part.

I think I get the meaning (The goverment has plans to build [a school], but since those were proceding slowly, on-site NGOs associations assisted in building it"), but I'm not sure how `として` fits in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the simple answer to your question is that [遅々として](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%81%85%E3%80%85%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6) is a set phrase, and is used commonly enough with `進まない` that the [whole thing](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%81%85%E3%80%85%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E9%80%B2%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) is in the dictionary as a set phrase.

That said, it's also worth keeping in mind that not every instance of `とする` and `として` necessarily have to be mean `as`. [とする](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) has quite a few different usages, and it can also just come about coincidentally with adverbs taking `と`, which is what happened here.

You might see constructions like

> 話を延々とする　(to speak endlessly)

or

> 漠然とした予感　(a vague suspicion)

both of which are not instances of `とする` meaning `as`, but the result of [延々](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%BB%B6%E3%80%85) and [漠然](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%BC%A0%E7%84%B6) being adverbs which take `と`.

Edit: Just for clarity's sake here, these two examples are slightly different things. `話を延々とする` is just a と-adverb in the middle of `話をする`, whereas `漠然とした予感` is a common pattern where `とした` is used after a と-adverb to qualify a noun. For the latter pattern, you can also find quite a few examples with an [quick search](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F&ref=sa), but trying to explain this construction is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I definitely have to switch dictionaries, in the ones I usually use there is neither ` 遅々として` nor `遅々として進まない`. Thanks a lot, that really helped, `として` is a form I struggle with sometime. Is `とする` something each と-adverb can take, or just for set phrases?

Comment: After you hit a certain point, monolingual dictionaries become pretty unavoidable. It's fine to try bilingual dictionaries (like Jisho) first, just don't stop there - there's a mountain of stuff you can only find on the monolingual dictionaries. As for `とする` and と-adverbs, I'll update my answer to make things a little clearer, but most commonly it's used as a way to qualify nouns.